# android SQLITE query distinct

Tags: android

I need help how to select distinct in android sqlite database?
i have tried query like this:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT nama_makanan FROM MAKANAN ORDER BY nama_makanan ASC", null);
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.isi_makanan, cursor, new String[] {"nama_makanan", "kategori", "icon"}, new int[] {R.id.txt_namamakanan, R.id.txt_kategori, R.id.img_icon});
```

but no result show...

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you have data in your database?

Comment: yes I'm sure, when i use  select * from MAKANAN it show all of the data.. I make database using class in eclipse. and i call database class to show database.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINC
```

should be -->

```
SELECT DISTINCT
```

You are missing the T

Comment: thankyou very much for your answer, yes i mean distinct... but it still no result...
please help me... is android sqlite database can do select distinct?

Comment: SQLite definitely supports SELECT DISTINCT - http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things.

First, post your logCat, it always helps. Second, this is most probably because Android requires _id columns for Cursors. Third you are only pulling one column and passing three to the cursor. If you only want to show nama_makanan then only tell the adapter to pull that column.

Try the following:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT nama_makanan as _id FROM MAKANAN ORDER BY nama_makanan ASC", null);
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.isi_makanan, cursor, new String[] {"_id"}, new int[] {R.id.txt_namamakanan});
```

Edited answer based on comments:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT nama_makanan as _id, kategori as kategori, icon as icon FROM MAKANAN ORDER BY nama_makanan ASC", null);
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.isi_makanan, cursor, new String[] {"_id", "kategori", "icon"}, new int[] {R.id.txt_namamakanan, R.id.txt_kategori, R.id.img_icon});
```

Comment: thankyou for the answer, i want to show 3 column... i use distinct because field nama_makanan have more than one data that same name.

Comment: i try to use your code, its work but its only show one column.. hows the code if i need 3 column? nama_makanan, kategori, icon.

Comment: That is something different, and you should be able to come by that by  yourself, just your original question with mine. The issue was the _id. I've edited my answer to reflect what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try following way,

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT(nama_makanan) FROM MAKANAN ORDER BY nama_makanan ASC", null);
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.isi_makanan, cursor, new String[] {"nama_makanan", "kategori", "icon"}, new int[] {R.id.txt_namamakanan, R.id.txt_kategori, R.id.img_icon});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these two queries for same result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT nama_makanan FROM Customers ORDER BY nama_makanan ASC;

SELECT nama_makanan FROM Customers GROUP BY nama_makanan ORDER BY nama_makanan ASC;
```